# Flutter : DefaultTabController Tabbar Tab Color not changing on selection

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar, statelesswidget

In my app I am using a DefaultTabController to display tabs which was working fine but i want to change the Tabbar Tab color when selecting a tab, which was not happening now. I used below code to highlight the selected tab color.

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(color: tabController?.index == 0 ? highlightColor : normalColor,border: Border.all(color: level1Color6,width: 2,style: BorderStyle.solid),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
```

Below is my complete code :

```
class TabHome extends StatelessWidget {
TabHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
void initState() {
    initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
    dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = getScreenWidth(context);
    final screenHeight = getScreenHeight(context);
    TabController? tabController;

    PreferredSizeWidget sizedAppBar = AppBar(
      title: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
           .....
        ],
      ),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                  .....
            ],
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    PreferredSizeWidget sizedTabBar = TabBar(
        controller: tabController,
        labelColor: textWhite1,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
        indicatorWeight: 2,
        isScrollable: true,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
        indicatorColor: highlightColor,
        indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0, right: 2.0,bottom: 3.0),
        indicator: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5), // Creates border
            color: highlightColor,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,

        ),
        labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric (horizontal: 1),
        tabs: [
            Container(
            width: mainTabWidth,
            height: mainTabHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: tabController?.index == 0 ? highlightColor : normalColor,border: Border.all(color: level1Color6,width: 2,style: BorderStyle.solid),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Tab(child:Text(tab1,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),),
            ),
            Container(
            width: mainTabWidth,
            height: mainTabHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: tabController?.index == 1 ? highlightColor : normalColor,border: Border.all(color: level1Color6,width: 2,style: BorderStyle.solid),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Tab(child:Text(tab2,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),),
            ),
            Container(
            width: mainTabWidth,
            height: mainTabHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: tabController?.index == 2 ? highlightColor : normalColor,border: Border.all(color: level1Color6,width: 2,style: BorderStyle.solid),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Tab(child:Text(tab3,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),),
            ),
            Container(
            width: mainTabWidth,
            height: mainTabHeight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: tabController?.index == 3 ? highlightColor : normalColor,border: Border.all(color: level1Color6,width: 2,style: BorderStyle.solid),borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
            child: Tab(child:Text(tab4,textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),),),
            ),
        ],
    );

    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final availableHeight = screenHeight - sizedAppBar.preferredSize.height - sizedTabBar.preferredSize.height - mediaQuery.padding.top;

    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
            BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => TabBloc()..add(TabInitialEvent()),
            )
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
            title: 'Tab Home',
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Scaffold(
            appBar: sizedAppBar,
            body: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 3,),
                    DefaultTabController(
                        length: 4, // length of tabs
                        initialIndex: 0,
                        child: Builder(
                            builder: (context) {
                            tabController = DefaultTabController.of(context);
                            tabController?.addListener(() {
                                print("New tab index: ${tabController?.index}");
                            });
                            return Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                        child: sizedTabBar,
                                    ),
                                    //SizedBox(height: 1.0),
                                    Container(
                                        height: availableHeight * 0.93, //height of TabBarView
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))
                                        ),
                                        child: TabBarView(
                                        controller: tabController,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                            Container(
                                            child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                getFirstTab(screenWidth,screenHeight),
                                                ],
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                            child: Center(
                                                child: Text('Display Tab 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                            child: Center(
                                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                                    child: Text('to Tab 3'),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                    print('Tab Now ${tabController?.index}');
                                                    tabController?.animateTo(1);
                                                    }
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                            Container(
                                            child: Center(
                                                child: Text('Display Tab 4', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    ],);
                            }
                        )
                    ),
                    ],
                )
            ),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }

    getFirstTab(double screenWidth, double screenHeight) {
        return BlocBuilder<TabBloc, TabState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
            return Expanded(
                child: Scrollbar(
                controller: controller,
                child: ListView(
                    controller: controller,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                       .........
                    ],
                ),
                )
            );
        },
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `TabBar`, you need to notify the view when the tab changes, to rebuild the view again, try this:

```
PreferredSizeWidget sizedTabBar = TabBar(
     onTap: (_){
        setState(() {});
     },
     ...
)
```

then you need to update you class to `StatefulWidget`, because you need to update your state.

Comment: setState will not work in stateless widget

Comment: so you need to update you class to stateful one. @KJEjava48

Comment: I was using state management so i can't update it to Stateful

Comment: instead of setState, you can define new event and new state then lunch that new event and that will rebuild the ui.

Comment: "I was using state management so i can't update it to Stateful" -  That's not true, you are not bound to use only stateless widgets just because you use state management like bloc, riverpod or provider. Of course it makes sense to keep it consistent, but sometimes there are cases where you need a stateful widget.

Comment: @eamirho3ein Yes, can u show it with code

Comment: @eamirho3ein  Since i am using PreferredSizeWidget for Tabbar i don't have an exact idea about how to apply state to sizedTabBar PreferredSizeWidget.

Answer (score 1):

You have to options to do so.

The first: is to use stateful widget instead of stateless widget so you can update the current page state using

```
setState((){});
```

The second: is to use one of the state management like getX, Provider, Bloc .. etc.

this will help you with bigger projects even if you're using stateless widget
you can update your current state so you can make changes to your screen while using Bloc you can do `emit(YourStateHere());`

Comment: Yes i want to use the second method, can u show it with code??

Comment: Since i am using PreferredSizeWidget for Tabbar i don't have an exact idea about how to apply state management to sizedTabBar PreferredSizeWidget.

Comment: @KJEjava48 You can read more about Flutter State Management [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Comment: @KJEjava48 If you're looking for Bloc Pattern you can visit their official [website](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/)